# su not properly logged when using byobu

Tags: sudo, byobu, su

We're seeing varations in our logs when a user su's from a byobu session vs. a regular shell session.  When using a regular session the lines in /var/log/auth.log look like this:

```
root@delta:/var/log# tail -n 0 -f auth.log | grep su
Aug  6 14:15:56 delta sudo:   chrish : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/chrish ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Aug  6 14:15:56 delta sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by chrish(uid=1000)
Aug  6 14:15:56 delta su[29322]: Successful su for root by root
Aug  6 14:15:56 delta su[29322]: + /dev/pts/3 root:root
Aug  6 14:15:56 delta su[29322]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by chrish(uid=0)
```

However, when that user is in a byobu and su's the lines look as follows:

```
root@delta:/var/log# tail -n 0 -f auth.log | grep su
Aug  6 14:14:26 delta sudo:   chrish : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/chrish ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
Aug  6 14:14:26 delta sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Aug  6 14:14:26 delta su[27243]: Successful su for root by root
Aug  6 14:14:26 delta su[27243]: + /dev/pts/2 root:root
Aug  6 14:14:26 delta su[27243]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

Notice how the lines which say "session opened for user root by" don't include a username like they do above?  Is this a misconfiguration or a bug that needs to be reported?  This is causing some of our log monitoring alerts to not fire.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I am able to reproduce your problem, exactly, in both [Byobu](http://byobu.co), as well as [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), which is used by `byobu-tmux`.  Curiously, this does not happen in `byobu-screen` or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).

This does look to me like a bug, somewhere in or around tmux or PAM.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this!  We're also having the same issues on a CentOS box, so I did a little comparison.  Here are my notes so far: https://gist.github.com/chrishas35/972fc8febad14bad1ae4

Comment: I see there that you logged a bug with GNU Screen...  I actually couldn't reproduce it with GNU Screen.  It might be worth filing a bug or asking about this on the tmux mailing list.

Comment: I logged a bug with GNU Screen as we can produce the bug on CentOS.  You're right about Ubuntu being good though...with them having the same base version of GNU Screen I find it pretty peculiar. We'll also open a discussion with tmux.